# Android filter not working backwards

Tags: android, list, filter

I have followed a question here and implemented filter in my adapter like this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter(){
    return new Filter(){

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<Event> list = events;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<Event> nlist = new ArrayList<>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i).getInterpretName();
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            clear();
            for (Event item : (List<Event>) results.values) {
                add(item);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    };
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The problem is, that when I delete a character from query, nothing changes. When I delete it whole, I get an empty list

Comment: add notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: where should i add it ?

Comment: Inside for Loop

Comment: Now it is crashing due to null object reference in publishResults

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the ArrayAdapter. I switched to BaseAdapter and everything works like charm